# Conditionally formatting kendo grid column issue with if statement in template

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-template

I am running into an issue trying to add a percentage sign to my value in one of my columns in the kendo grid using a template, what I am using is..

```
template: "#if(Markup != null){ #=kendo.format('{0:p}', Markup / 100)# }#"
```

So if the Markup value is not null then I want it to show the percentage sign, but when I run the grid all I get returning is my column is

```
=kendo.format('{0:p}', Markup / 100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I like to use template as a function:

```
template: function(item) {
    if(item.markup) {
        return kendo.format('{0:p0}', item.markup / 100);
    }

    return item.name;
}
```

Simple example: [template as a function](https://dojo.telerik.com/UMiNiBAX)

Or you can use it your way:

```
template: "#= data.markup ? kendo.format('{0:p}', data.markup / 100): 'N/A' #"
```

Dojo: [inline template](https://dojo.telerik.com/eyEWUYUq)

NOTE:

```
"#if(Markup != null){ #=kendo.format('{0:p}', Markup / 100)# }#"
                       \--- this hash closes script, 
                            everithing after that is string.
                            Thats why you see
                            =kendo.format('{0:p}', Markup / 100) in grid
```